# Camera orbiting where ever i drag my mouse

Tags: 3d-view

I want the camera to orbit the object after pressing Numbad . but it won't orbit the object instead it basically orbits where ever i drag my mouse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have probably checked the Auto Depth option in the preferences. Uncheck it and you should be fine.

[image]